# Task Pattern for Java Web Applications

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications, multitasking

It's pretty common to see some flavor of the *Task Pattern* implemented on enterprise Swing applications. It just makes sense: you'll have a lot of complex user commands that may take (differing) long periods of time to complete, and you can't expect your users to just sit there and wait.

But what about its practicality in a dynamic web application? Say I've got some web app that is heavily-based in AJAX so that users can issue all sorts of commands all over the page , and each of those commands get sent as standalone requests back to the server.

Is the task pattern an appropriate "request handling mechanism" for such an application, or are todays web containers so advanced & multi-threaded that doing so would be overkill?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Isn't categorizing HTTP request as tasks or command context dependent? Also, RESTful architecture solves this problem to an extent by means of "resources" and "verbs" in case that's what you are looking for.

Comment: COMET/Long-Poll AJAX are both methods available currently to handle extended request processing with notification/callback. While not a pattern in and of themselves you can consider them enabling technologies for your scenario.

Comment: These are all great suggestions, but I'm simply asking if the [Task Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduler_pattern) is a good solution to implement with business logic-processing beans in the backend.

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay I think that pretty much addresses the core concept behind my original question. Thanks again for checking back in and answering my follow-up questions as well! I'll wait a few more days and if you'd like to just copy your last response into an actual answer (instead of a comment) I'd be happy to check you as the accepted answer-er.

Comment: You are of course welcome, good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using @Sanjay T. Sharma's response as an answer. I'm doing this because I like to have an acceptance rate of 100% and it's pretty obvious that for some reason he/she does not want to answer this question.

**(Sanjay's) Answer**:

"...things which don't demand instant feedback to the user are better off being handled on independent servers/services while the "web container" can focus on serving web clients. Carrying on with your example, when the answer is accepted, the updation of "accept rate" isn't exactly "sent back" to the client after it finishes but is reflected in the underlying data store asynchronously which is showed to the user the next time a response is created for the user."

Comment: Though I don't mind not receiving reputation for this thread, it's untrue that I didn't want to answer this question. I didn't copy my comment content as an answer because I didn't want to give other posters the impression that the question has been answered. Plus I was assuming a comment update saying that you are done waiting and would like me bring a closure to this thread. Think about it, if I didn't want to answer/help, why would I follow up with the queries in the comment section?:)